# Signing key rollover in Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, nuget-package, msdn

I am using the method mentioned in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#vs2012 to automatically rollover the certificates.

However the below line of code searches for `<issuerNameRegistry>` as a child element of the `<identityConfiguration>` which is deprecated according to the msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568647(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry.WriteToConfig(metadataAddress, configPath);
```

Is there any updates coming soon to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry nuget package which searches for `<issuerNameRegistry>`  as a child element of `<securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>`

I am able to get the code working as there is support for backward compatibility. However I do not want to use deprecated methods

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked best was to use the different versions of Visual Studio and Office 365 to see the differences in approach.

The current way has a little different syntax and all of that can be discovered by using the ASP.Net Web Application template.

If you use the template in vs2013 you will see the setup you must currently have with `<federationConfiguration>` and `<identityConfiguration>` sections, `TenantDbContext`, `IdentityConfig` and it wired up in your global.asax

If you do the same thing in vs2015 you will see that there is no longer any configuration at all besides appSettings. Everything is magically wired up through a partial class at the root called Startup.cs with more of the content hidden in the App_Start folder. This is the OWIN pipeline and has a much different feel than what you have been used to. For the better. A lot of the identity terminology is the same, the keys are the same, the management in AAD is the same so you get to reuse a lot of your code. OWIN does require MVC5 so if you can't upgrade you are pretty good where you are.

The [`ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.validatingissuernameregistry(v=vs.115).aspx) has been replaced by a [`TokenCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.tokencache.aspx) but the concept is the same, EF store for rollover safety.

More Reading:

[Authentication, Authorization and OWIN – Who Moved My Cheese?](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2014/10/2014105aspnet-identity-oauth-and-loginaspx/)

[Understanding OWIN Forms authentication in MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5/)